# Is Reactive Extensions 2.1 PCL compatible with Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, system.reactive, xamarin, portable-class-library

Riddle me this:

Can the new PCL version of Reactive Extensions be made to work with Xamarin?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. But check out https://github.com/mono/rx/tree/rx-oss-v2.1/Rx/NET/Source/Rx_Xamarin for versions that do work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. At the moment, you will need to switch to the beta channel of the Xamarin tools which implement Mono 3.0. This can be done via Tools > Options > Xamarin in Visual Studio 2012.

[Xamarin.Android 4.7 Information](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_4/xamarin.android_4.7)

[Xamarin.iOS 6.3 Information](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_6/xamarin.ios_6.3)

The [ReactiveUI project](http://www.reactiveui.net/) should have all of the libraries that you need. [Here](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tree/rxui5-master/ext) is a link to the libraries folder on their nuget site.

Comment: Those binaries actually *aren't* the PCL ones from the official NuGet project, they're the ones from the link I posted above. But you're right that you need the Xamarin Beta/Alpha to use them, good point