# Rx 2.1 & Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, system.reactive, portable-class-library

I'm trying to build an app on Xamarin that targets multiple platforms but uses rx. So far I've created a core PCL which I would like to use rx, but when I tried to import the rx 2.1 nuget package I get the following error:

> You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'portable-net40+win+sl50+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10', but the
>   package does not contain any assembly references or content files that
>   are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

I am aware that there is an rx component in the xamarin store, but it doesn't seem like I can add this into my PCL.

It seems to me that ideally I want the core rx libraries in the PCL, but that platform specific schedulers should be imported in the platform specific app implementations.

What is the best way to proceed at the moment?

n.b. I am aware this has been touched upon in other questions, but the answers pre-date release channel PCL support in Xamarin.

edit:

I've modified my PCL to target .net 4.5 (and removed silverlight). I can now pull in the rx nuget package but I'm getting a build warning that it cannot resolve 'system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, Xamarin Stable can't build PCLs (Alpha *just* got it, I haven't experimented with it though). Just use multiple csproj files at the moment (see https://github.com/paulcbetts/starter-mobile for an example)

Comment: Is there still a problem using '.' is ios projects as I am sure I saw that convention in the xamarin docs?

Comment: @DanH I still try to avoid it - I would get errors where Xamarin would either try to silently remove the '.' and break stuff, or it'd just flat-out say, "You can't have a dot here"

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Paul Betts's ReactiveUI on GitHub](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI). I've not done any Xamarin development personally, but I know that project uses Rx and is organised to run on multiple platforms including Xamarin - it will probably give you the right approach.

Paul Betts's also mentioned this in another question: [Is Reactive Extensions 2.1 PCL compatible with Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599214/is-reactive-extensions-2-1-pcl-compatible-with-xamarin?rq=1)

Comment: Yes that's the answer I found that predates PCL support in non alpha build of Xamarin ;) Was hoping to find out the current best practise as the recommendations seem to be in constant flux.

Comment: Just looking through the Rx source history and there's a recently added PLLITE portable target that might be worth looking at. The relevant changeset is http://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/11681796da9a14e0ed3a085ed4c8c29c2cb93b91

Comment: You may be onto something with the 4.5 requirement. I changed the PCL to that and now I can pull in the nuget rx package. Just got build probs now as I can't find where the build target is in xamarin studio!

Comment: Oh right. I deleted that comment because it looks to be that they'd sorted .NET 4.0 portability, but maybe not I guess! Can't help you with Xamarin I'm afraid. I must get onto that!

Answer (score 2):

With the stable release (Xamarin.Android 4.10.1), it's still weird as I found out. I have the followinig setup:

(1) PCL-Library with profile 49 (.net 4.5, Windows 8, Xamarin Android/iOS).
(2) Xamarin.Android App referencing (1).

If Rx is added from Nuget to both projects, it adds "targetFramework="portable-net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10" to packages.config and adds references to "packages\Rx-Core.2.1.30214.0\lib\Portable-Net45+WinRT45+WP8\System.Reactive.Core.dll" to both projects.

(1) builds fine then, but (2) doesn't (missing system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime, as in the initial question).

Changing the Rx-path in (2) to "packages\Rx-Core.2.1.30214.0\lib\net40\System.Reactive.Core.dll" however works, though (2) still references (1).

I had a look into the Rx code. References to System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime are guarded by #if HAS_WINRT, so I guess a library that relies on WinRT shouldn't have been put into a Xamarin.Android project by NuGet in the first place.

It's okay for me to change references manually, don't know what will happen if Rx gets an update.

But why is it ok to have the wrong dll in the PCL-project (1) and let (2) reference (1) ?

Comment: There is now rx 2.2 on the beta channel which added some more build targets - might be worth a shot? I've not come back to xamarin as my trial expired and it wasted a day of my life.

Comment: Still doesn't work with 2.2 beta. The dll that is added to both projects is from "portable-windows8+net45+wp8" (was "Portable-Net45+WinRT45+WP8"). Still, building the App fails with missing System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll. I can't see anything that is needed from that reference so I guess it shouldn't be there at all.

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I was having another look at xamarin and now seem to be hitting different problems instead!

Comment: From what I read elsewhere, the missing classes will be in on of the next Versions of Xamarin.Android. Nothing official though...

Comment: Rx has been perfectly usable in PCL projects for quite a while now.. .